# Reorganize & rebuild for indexes on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried to create a database maintenance plan with SQL Server Management Studio with SQL Server 2008.
If I use database maintenance plan wizard and set it for all to rebuild index, then run the package, it is failed on a table.

Then I just find out the table in object explorer and use Rebuild All indexes from popup menu on this table, it is fine.

So confused. Does it mean these two way requiring different setting? How to resolve this problem?

Another question is:
If apply Rebuild index, then no need to use Reorganize, right?

Here is the error message from job history:
Message
Executed as user: xxx\sqlservice. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.5500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  7:21:27 PM  Progress: 2012-04-14 19:21:27.96     Source: {9FA4339C-7D29-4059-871B-5160B63DBBA0}      Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2012-04-14 19:21:30.09     Source: Rebuild Index Task      Executing query "USE [MyDB]  ".: 0% complete  End Progress  Error: 2012-04-14 19:21:30.12     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Rebuild Index Task Execute SQL Task     Description: Executing the query "ALTER INDEX [MyTab1_PK] ON [dbo].[MyTab1] ..." failed with the following error: "Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  7:21:27 PM  Finished: 7:21:30 PM  Elapsed:  2.668 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

But if I do it on the table MyTab1 individually, it is fine.
I removed MyTab1 from the list for rebuild, the I will get another error on another table with different error message.

Comment: What does "it is failed on a table" mean? Do you get an actual error message? Could you share it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message here?

Comment: @RajivVarma isn't that the same question I asked?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didnt notice it before I posted my comment. Take it easy Aaron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're setting up your maintenance plan, you need to make sure you uncheck the box, in the rebuild indexes subplan, entitled:

> Keep index online while reindexing

I suspect you or someone checked that box when creating/editing the maintenance plan, because it shouldn't be checked by default (which is why the error doesn't occur when you rebuild the index manually).

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is why. Will check and try it again.

Comment: Yes, after I removed the checkbox , it's fine now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, Index Rebuild drops the existing Index and Recreates it, so there is no need to use reorganize (that only works on the leaf nodes of the index.)

and the error is pretty simple: "Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server."

Online rebuilds are online available on the Enterprise version of SQL Server and your version probably isn't, so just set the operation not to be run "Online" on you Wizard.

Quick explanation: An online Rebuild, rebuilds the indexes on the tempDB making it available to the queries while it is being rebuilt. It is used when the operation takes a lot of time and you cant afford to leave the index "unused".

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I had an offline database, which I was expecting to drop in the near future. After the database is dropped, the problem is went away.